# <Query> vs graphql Hoc which is best way to hook graphql query with component in react apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

React Apollo 2.1 introduce `<Query/>` component to hook graphql query with component.

```
<Query query={GET_DOGS}>
{({ loading, error, data }) => {
  if (loading) return "Loading...";
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

  return (
    <select name="dog" onChange={onDogSelected}>
      {data.dogs.map(dog => (
        <option key={dog.id} value={dog.breed}>
          {dog.breed}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}}
```

In older version we use graphql Hoc to hook query.

```
export default compose(
  graphql(GET_DOGS)(MyComponent),
  withLoader
)(Component)
```

Here withLoader HOC handles loading, error and data state.

```
function withLoader(WrappedComponent) {
    class comp extends React.PureComponent {
       render(){
          return this.props.isData?<WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>:<Loading/>
       }
    }
}
```

So which is best way to hook query and why? Is it wise decision to shift all queries which was written using graphql HOC into latest `<Query/>` component.

I'm not getting any pros writing a query according Apollo 2.1 . Personally writing a query using hoc looks clean and decoupled. But some people doesn't recommended use hoc.

Comment: I did not find anything telling that apollo has deprecated the hoc's version, but all apollo's documentation use the Query component, so I think that this is the suggested way.

Comment: Are they doing any kind of optimisation to implement Query Component? Because using graphql HOC, components looks clean and decouple from query logic.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO `<Query/>` components were introduced **only to simplify the initial barrier for newcomers**. They look like other components and are easy to read.

Their use is limited to simple use cases - using them quickly becomes complicated in more complex scenarios.

Try to use data from `<Query/>` in other life cycle or try to use a few of them (`<Mutation/>`) in one `render`.

You'll quickly be back in composing HOCs ;)